# Best practices for configuration and property files with artifactory / maven

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

We've got a lot of java property files as well as JBoss configuration files that need to be deployed with our app.  Currently, we've got a maven build that puts all of the .jar and .war files into artifactory, but NOT the .property files or JBoss configurations.  Is there a best practice for storing these in artifactory?  If they should not be stored there, where should they be stored so they can be easily deployed with the binaries?

Answer (score 0):

If they are application configurations, they have to be shipped with the application, i.e. in the jar file or the war file. It's not a good idea to deploy them separately.

Best place to put them is in [resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) folder of your maven project, or in WEB-INF if it is a web application.

Apart from the concern for deploying or storing them, if you want to share them between various components in your infrastructure, think of a better approach, like persisting them in a key-value store, a Database, or a shared file.

Comment: once you zip them inside the jars and wars it's complicated to change them. Keeping them aside simplifies runtime configuration.

Comment: Some configurations are included in resources (like the Spring application-context files), but many either need to be changed frequently (hard to do when it is inside the jar/war) or apply to multiple binaries (violates the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.  Also, the JBoss configuration files don't lend themselves to being in resources at all.

Comment: Just follow best practices. Your question concerns maven and what I explained was only for application specific default configuration. If you need better control you have to implement the mechanism for accessing a config file outside your app or use a framework like spring to do that for you. For example you can determine a home folder for you app (With an ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE, or a Java System Property or a mixture of them with fallbacks, ...) and put the config file under a conf directory in that home folder.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping properties files in Artifactory is a good practice. Make sure to tie them with the application binaries by using properties (e.g. build-name, build-number, etc). You can automate this by using [build integration](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration) features of Artifactory and tagging the artifacts and the properties files during the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that tha application server configuration files should be separated from the application file..

If you think about the spring configuration files, they are hard coupled with the application, so they should be inside resources directory, but the application server config files are not coupled with the apllication so they schould be stored separatelly..

I think a best way is to use some Maven plugin that accomplish this needs...

something like:

visit https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/

than...sure, artifactory could be a good location to save the configuration files, not inside the jar, but separatelly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best practice, both solutions are fine. In practice usually it depends on the deployment tools in use, your application architecture (e.g. are config files shared across components? etc.), the number of environments, the need for encryption of config files but also your release cycles (do you need to repackage for every configuration change?) etc.

For example if using ansible the default setup is to store configuration and deployment instructions in a VCS. Which mean all what remains into Artifactory in that case are the binaries.